# Get screen position of Image (or actor) in Libgdx Stage

Tags: java, libgdx

I have this piece of code:

```
Image myImage = new Image(new Texture("data/file.png"));
```

How to get `myImage` position on a screen?  I tried `myImage.getX()` and `myImage.getImageX()` both always return 0.0. What's wrong?

Comment: getX() should do the job..  did you try to move it and check ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I believe `getX()` and `getY()` on an `Actor` are relative to their parent container, so you'll need to convert the coordinates to "stage" coordinates, and then from there to "screen" coordinates.  (I think there is an easier way to do this, so there may be a better answer out there).

```
Image myImage = ...;
Vector2 coords = new Vector2(myImage.getX(), myImage.getY());
myImage.localToStageCoordinates(/*in/out*/coords);
myImage.getStage().stageToScreenCoordinates(/*in/out*/coords);

System.out.println("Image X " +myImage.get()+ " maps to screen " +coords.x);
```

Comment: It's necessary to create Vector2 with zero coordinates (Vector2 coords = new Vector2(0, 0); )

Answer (score 1):

Just a guess!!! - Moving the image & checking for position but getX() returning 0.0 might be because its the camera which moves & produces the movement effect, image may havenot been moved at all & tsayed at the initial position of 0.0 (i think this might be the thing you are missing)

Answer (score 0):

Now `Actor`s have `localToScreenCoordinates` to get what you need in one call:

```
Vector2 screenPosition = myImage.localToScreenCoordinates(new Vector2(0f, 0f))
```